# GWT Cell Table Problem

Tags: java, gwt, collections, widget

I am getting problem in setting a cell table. I want to generate a Cell table from a list of Strings which are contact numbers. I am googling this but i'm not finding any working exampple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, these are what you want:
      http://www.coderanch.com/t/516823/GWT/Cell-Widget-Table-GWT-expanded